# Pandas iterrows loop isn't made faster with list comprehension nor multithreading

Tags: pandas, multithreading, performance, loops

I have a loop running on each row of a pandas dataframe. I need to run two operations in order to calculate new string fields in the dataframe. These dataframes come from several very large files, rendering it essential that this function takes as little time as possible.

For reproductibility's sake, here are two small dataframes that look like the ones I'm using:

```
import json
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from geolib import geohash as pgh
import time

coords1 = [[1.3093500680264314, 44.14597523454133],
[1.309362565037715, 44.14597542723667],
[1.3093750620490838, 44.1459756199306],
[1.3093875590605368, 44.145975812623114],
[1.3094000560720744, 44.14597600531418]]

coords2 = [[1.3123256948057254, 44.14597606298388],
[1.312338191827267, 44.145976255340116],
[1.3123506888488932, 44.14597644769494],
[1.312363185870604, 44.14597664004834],
[1.3123756828923991, 44.14597683240032]]

elev1 = [177.2, 177.1, 177.0, 177.0, 176.9]

elev2 = [164.3, 164.5, 164.7, 165.0, 165.3]

points1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'center': coords1, 'elevation': elev1})
points2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'center': coords2, 'elevation': elev2})

inputs = [points1, points2]
```

The original iterrows function looks like this:

```
def asc_to_geohash_polygons(gdf, processed_geohashes):
    
    start_time1 = time.time()
    
    elevation_data=[]
    for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
        geohash_code = pgh.encode(row['center'][1], row['center'][0], precision=9)

        if geohash_code not in processed_geohashes:
            processed_geohashes.add(geohash_code)
            bounds = pgh.bounds(geohash_code)
            sw = bounds.sw
            ne = bounds.ne
            poly = Polygon([(sw.lon, sw.lat),
                            (ne.lon, sw.lat),
                            (ne.lon, ne.lat),
                            (sw.lon, ne.lat),
                            (sw.lon, sw.lat)])
            feature = {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "geohash": geohash_code,
                    "elevation": row['elevation']
                },
                "geometry": poly.__geo_interface__
            }
            features.append(feature)
            elevation_data.append([geohash_code, row['elevation']])
    
    end_time1 = time.time()
    print(f"Timer 1: {end_time1 - start_time1} seconds")
            
    return features, elevation_data
```

This function is then called by a subsequent one and then executed:

```
def process_all_files_in_folder(gdfs, output_geojson_path):
    all_features = []
    elevation_dict = {}  # Using a dictionary to prevent duplicates
    processed_geohashes = set()  # Global set to track processed geohashes

    all_files = [f for f in gdfs]

    for file in all_files:
        temp_data, temp_elevations = asc_to_geohash_polygons(file, processed_geohashes)
        all_features.extend(temp_data)

        for geohash, elevation in temp_elevations:
            elevation_dict[geohash] = elevation


    all_elevations = [[geohash, elevation] for geohash, elevation in elevation_dict.items()]
    print(all_elevations)
    with open(output_geojson_path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": all_features}, f, indent=4)
        

process_all_files_in_folder(inputs, 'output.geojson')
```

I ran several timing checks across my code and found that the iterrows bit is the one taking longer, so I tried changing it to (1) functions implemented with .apply() , (2) list comprehensions, (3) multithreading. All of which ended up producing worst results than the original one. Below are the attempts to change the asc_to_geohash_polygons() function:

(1) .APPLY()

```
def encode_geohash(lat_lon_pair):
    return pgh.encode(lat_lon_pair[1], lat_lon_pair[0], precision=9)
        
def get_feature(geohash, elevation):
    bounds = pgh.bounds(geohash)
    sw = bounds.sw
    ne = bounds.ne
    poly = Polygon([(sw.lon, sw.lat),
                    (ne.lon, sw.lat),
                    (ne.lon, ne.lat),
                    (sw.lon, ne.lat),
                    (sw.lon, sw.lat)])
    feature = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "geohash": geohash,
            "elevation": elevation
        },
        "geometry": poly.__geo_interface__
    }
    return feature

geohash_data = gdf['center'].apply(encode_geohash)
elevation_dataframe = pd.concat([geohash_data.rename('geohash'), gdf['elevation']], axis=1)
elevation_data = elevation_dataframe.tolist()
features = elevation_dataframe.apply(get_feature, axis=1).tolist()
processed_geohashes.update(geohash_data.tolist())
```

(2) LIST COMPREHENSION

```
geohash_data = gdf['center'].apply(encode_geohash)
        
gdf['geohash'] = geohash_data
        
features = [get_feature(geohash, elevation) for elevation, geohash in zip(gdf['elevation'], gdf['geohash'])]
        
elevation_data = [[geohash,elevation] for geohash, elevation in zip(gdf['geohash'], df['elevation'])]
        
processed_geohashes.update(geohash_data)
```

(3) MULTITHREADING

```
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
    from threading import Lock

    features = []
    
    hash_lock = Lock()

    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)
    
    def add_to_list(row):
        
        geohash_code = pgh.encode(row['center'][1], row['center'][0], precision=9)
        with hash_lock:
            if geohash_code in processed_geohashes:
                return False
            else:
                processed_geohashes.add(geohash_code)
        bounds = pgh.bounds(geohash_code)
        sw = bounds.sw
        ne = bounds.ne
        poly = Polygon([(sw.lon, sw.lat),
                        (ne.lon, sw.lat),
                        (ne.lon, ne.lat),
                        (sw.lon, ne.lat),
                        (sw.lon, sw.lat)])
        feature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "geohash": geohash_code,
                "elevation": row['elevation']
            },
            "geometry": poly.__geo_interface__
        }
        features.append(feature)
        elevation_data.append([geohash_code, row['elevation']])
        return True

    tasks = []

    for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
        tasks.append(pool.submit(add_to_list, row))

    for task in tasks:
        task.result()
        
    end_time3 = time.time()
    print(f"Timer 3: {end_time3 - start_time3} seconds")
```

What am I missing here? I realize vectorization would also be a possibility, but since I'm generating strings, it wouldn't be of much help.

Comment: Multi-threading should not help here because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). It is only useful for modules releasing it but most don't (and even when they do, it often does not scale). This is a well known limitation of CPython (since decades). In general, the solution is to use multiprocessing, but I am not sure you can use it efficiently here (data transfer and pickling will certainly be a bottleneck). Python is not a great tool for parallelism (nor performance in general).

Comment: Vectorization is generally the way to go for fast dataframes. Note that having lists (and more generally objects) in dataframes is not efficient (vectorization is fast only for native types supported by Numpy, like integers, floats and fixe-sized strings overall). Here calls to `pgh` and `Polygon` tends to make vectorization particularly difficult at first glance. One need to *profile the code* to know the bottleneck but maybe Python is simply not suited to compute such a task efficiently...

Comment: Yes profiling the code would be a good start. Iterrows tends to be slow.